# how to convert Source type converter to room

Tags: java, android, type-conversion, android-room

I am developing a news app and implemented but I am not able to convert model class to typeconverter below my model class

```
 @Entity
@ForeignKey(entity = Source.class,parentColumns = "source", childColumns = "content")
public class Article {
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("source")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name ="source")
    @TypeConverters(SourceTypeConverter.class)
    private Source source;

    public Source getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(Source source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @SerializedName("author")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "author")
    private String author;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "url")
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("urlToImage")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "urlToImage")
    private String urlToImage;

    @SerializedName("publishedAt")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "publishedAt")
    private String publishedAt;
    @SerializedName("content")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "content")
    private String content;





    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrlToImage() {
        return urlToImage;
    }

    public void setUrlToImage(String urlToImage) {
        this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
    }

    public String getPublishedAt() {
        return publishedAt;
    }

    public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
        this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

below my SourceTypeConverter class

```
public class  SourceTypeConverter {

@TypeConverter
   public static Source ConvertSource(Source source){
   return source ==   null ? null : new Source(source);
}




}
```

below Source.java
public class Source {

```
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

public Source(Source source) {
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

below I am getting C:\Users\Edgar\Desktop\Sport News\app\src\main\java\edgar\yodgorbek\sportnews\model\Article.java:18: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private Source source;

```
below my database class
@Database(entities = {Article.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public  abstract class SportNewsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
  public  abstract SportNewsDao sportNewsDao();
}
```

Comment: Please post your converter class and what fields you need to convert?

Comment: @w201 I am not able to convert thats why I have posted my code please help me

Comment: what is Source class? Now your type converter hasn't sense at all. It returns type that database unsupported. Provide code for Source class

Comment: @w201 I have added my database I am getting error as well I have error as well please check my updated post above

Answer (score 0):

According to our chat in linkedin I could say that you are very ungrateful man. Your problem that room can't convert file type Source that you have in model. So you need to create converter from Source class to type that sqlite supported.

According to your latest published code I could say that you try to do something wrong. You have two tables: Source and Article. And you want to store link to Source inside Article.

1. Delete your type converter
2. Read this http://androidkt.com/database-relationships/
3. In short you need to create foreign key for Source in Article. This is one-to-one relation.

Comment: I HAVE ADDED CODE PLEASE CHECK IT

Comment: please check my updated code I have done as you told me but I am getting error as well